# Algorithm for lazy-loading mapview annotations

Tags: ios, maps, mkmapview

I'm working on a Map app that loads locations from an API. I have the code worked out so when the user pans a significant distance, the API is queried for locations within x kilometers, and the annotations are replaced.

I'm coding for iOS, but this would apply to any map app.

Everything works at this point, but I'm unhappy with my algorithm for what a significant distance is, and what radius of locations to load. A few things I'm thinking through-

- The map view is a rectangle, taller than it is wide.
- Loading locations within x kilometers gives you a circle
- Users can zoom in and out
- Users can pan N,S,E,W
- Re-loading with every small change of view will make for poor user experience - there needs to be a threshold
- There should be locations outside the view, so users can pan and zoom to a certain degree before reloading
- Given a rectangle inside a circle, users panning up or down will reach the edges of the circle earlier than when panning right and left
- To conserve resources, not all locations are shown when zoomed out too wide, so zooming in may reveal new locations
- Zooming out will reveal new locations

Any suggestions on what kind of algorithm I should be doing? I'm looking to determine the following variables-

- Radius of locations to load given screen width
- Threshold of change (panning and zooming) before reloading spots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution for raster maps is to cut the image in to tiles and load the ones "near" where the viewer is. You could do this for your data by loading additional points after panning/zooming without removing what is there. If your code for retrieving the new points is run in a background thread the user won't notice and with every pan they will always end up in a spot that already has data for them and while they look at that you go and load more data for their next pan. You'll need to work out how far they can go in one move. Longitude is easy, just take the longitudinal difference (i.e. right-left) and that's how far they could drag their finger and thus the map. So if your map view is 1 degree wide you should already have data from one degree to the map's right and one degree to the map's left. Latitude is harder since it changes as you move away from the equator. top to bottom there is a different measurement to if you're looking at Scotland. The principle is the same though. Work out how far the user could scroll in 1 drag and have preload that data. If you think of a 3x3 grid like a telephone pad. The map view is at the 5 button and you need to have all the surround buttons preloaded. The the mapview is dragged to the side so it is now looking at the 6 square you need to load in the additional square beyond that without loosing the data that is on the screen. You could either make three calls for to the right, above and to the right, above right and below right. or do one call and get all the new data in one call.

Of course if your call to fetch the new data is a bit slow and the user could pan twice before you receive an answer maybe you need to fetch a larger area. So you'd be at the center of a 5x5 grid and when the view moves towards the edge you have to fetch another row or column.

I hope that helps.